# How can I determine the size of my app store bundle?

Tags: ios, appstore

I made a very simple game. It only has Facebook, and Twitter share icons but it does have Ad Networks SDKs and adapters. My entire folder that contains all the SDK's is currently 200mb. The inmobi SDK alone takes 40mb and it is pretty huge for a super simple game.

Do the files in these folders contribute to the size of my app? Will this be the final app size when submitted on the appstore?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case people have doubt regarding the difference in size of the binary before uploading to iTunes and after uploading to iTunes here is the calculation:-

Apple is encrypting the executable file. By doing so its size doesn’t change much but its contents do which usually can no longer be compressed as much as before. By putting all this together i came up with a way to calculate the maximum size of your App in the App Store (it will most likely be less than this):

```
open the .app bundle via right-click -> Show Package Contents (on Mac)
locate the executable file and remember its (uncompressed) size (Size “A”)
delete the executable from the bundle
zip the bundle and remember the bundle’s compressed size (Size “B”)
```

Size “C” are the 100 KB from the additional files added to the bundle by Apple. The final calculation for the maximum size of your App is as follows:

A + B + C = maximum size of your App after approval

The calculation put in words:

(uncompressed executable size) + (app bundle compressed but without executable) + 0,1 MB = maximum size of your App after approval